# Why does comparing two files using FC.exe with /b option produce different results between manual and batch execution?

Tags: batch-file

I try to compare two files byte by byte using `fc.exe` with option `/b` for a binary compare.

When I run the command from within a command prompt window, the output lists the binary differences.

For example the command:

```
C:\Work\jan21\script>fc.exe /b C:\abc\2.0\common.c C:\Users\rakeshk\Desktop\download_break\final\common.c >b.txt
```

results in `b.txt` containing:

```
Comparing files C:\ABC\2.0\common.c and C:\USERS\RAKESHK\DESKTOP\DOWNLOAD_BREAK\FINAL\COMMON.C
00000994: 20 09
00000995: 20 69
00000996: 49 6E
00000997: 4E 74
00000998: 20 0D
00000999: 20 0A
0000099A: 55 20
...
```

And at end **FC** printed:

```
C:\USERS\RAKESHK\DESKTOP\DOWNLOAD_BREAK\FINAL\COMMON.C longer than C:\ABC\2.0\common.c
```

But when I run in batch file for example this command line

```
fc.exe /b !FILE1! !FILE2!>c.txt
```

the file `c.txt` contains

```
Comparing files C:\USERS\RAKESHK\DESKTOP\DOWNLOAD_BREAK\FINAL\COMMON.C longer than C:\ABC\2.0\common.c
FC: no differences encountered
```

Why is **FC** printing that there are no differences encountered although the files have different contents?

Comment: Have you tried using short filenames for the compare?

Comment: yes,.. i have tried but its showing same behaviour.

Comment: Honestly, the output of your `c.txt` file is very strange. I can't imagine how it can be (re)produced. Are you certain you haven't mixed up anything? I mean, is it *exactly* what the actual output looks like? Taking a look at your *complete* batch script *might* reveal something pertaining to the issue, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I created two files:

### x.txt (7 bytes)

```
abcdefg
```

### y.txt (16 bytes)

```
abcdefg
hijklmn
```

When comparing using `/b`, it didn't report any differences because the `/b` option shows the differences byte-by-byte.  Once it comes to the end of the smaller file, it stops comparing.  In this test, it only compared the first 7 bytes, then it reported y.txt is longer than x.txt.

I'm guessing that your two files are identical to the end of the smaller file, which is why it didn't report any differences.  In my test case, it did not report `no differences encountered`.  Perhaps that is because you are running on a different OS and you likely found a bug in `FC.EXE`...  I'm using WinSvr2008R2.  Running `ver` from DOS reports `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]` for me.  The file details for `FC` are:

```
07/13/2009  06:14 PM            19,968 fc.exe
```

If I view the details via Windows Explorer, I see:

```
File Description  -  DOS 5 File Compare Utility
File Version      -  6.1.7600.16385
```

.

### Edit Jan 28, 2013

Since you are doing a binary compare, just to see if the files are different, you can do it without generating a large binary diff file.  If you download the Microsoft **[File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)** and ensure the `fciv.exe` is somewhere in your path, then you can write the following batch file to determine if two files are the same or different.

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "skip=3 delims= " %%i in ('fciv -md5 %1') do set md5_1=%%i
for /f "skip=3 delims= " %%i in ('fciv -md5 %2') do set md5_2=%%i

if "!md5_1!"=="!md5_2!" (echo Files are the same) else (echo Files are different)

set md5_1=
set md5_2=

endlocal
```

Comment: I am also using same version of fc.exe. and os is windows 7.
Any other option to compare two files byte by byte.

Comment: I don't know of any other native DOS way to compare the differences.  I typically use Beyond Compare though, so I haven't had the need to find anything else...  You could download and MD5 hash utility and create an MD5 hash for both files and compare that to see if they are the same.  You can download the MD5 utility from MS here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Comment: I expanded my answer to include an example of how to use MD5s to tell if the two files are different.